# About getting area from DEM below 5000 and below 3000 m elevation?

Tags: python, dem

I want to get the area from the DEM which is below 5000 and 3000. Actually I need those two areas for my Regression Model to calculate the discharge. In that case, how can I find out using python. I need to calculate in each cell of the stream segment. I have tried with Surface Volume tool but it is taking too long time as i need to calculate for all the cells along the stream segments. Is there any easy and fast way to get this information.

Answer (score 2):

To extract cells below 5000 meters/any unit, you should use [Con](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z00000005000000).

Write the SQL expression like "Value < 5000" (or change value to what you need).

This function can also be used in Python scripts.

Comment: Yes I have tried with that also but the problem in my case is I need to have watershed for each cell and use Con for that derived watershed which is taking too much time for whole stream... Can't I make it faster.. Is there a way to make those processes faster using Python.

Comment: Well, not exactly sure what you mean with "a watershed for each cell", you can hardly delineate catchment areas for every cell. Also, calling a function from Python doesn't make it run faster (at least not to any significant level). However, you can automate a >workflow< so you wont have to call each function manually. 
In some cases there are tricks to make a function compute faster, like using in-memory workspace, but if you have a large DEM that might not be feasible.

Comment: I need to calculate discharge at each cell of the stream using data of area which is below 5000 and 3000. In order to do so, I am creating watershed at each cell and after that I am using Con() function to calculate area. This is taking too much time and crashes frequently what can be solution for this.